# Flutter list, chips and MultiSelect

Tags: flutter, multi-select

I am trying to transfer the result of a query to a list but it is not working properly.
Below you will find the source code, it will be more clear.

I'm getting this error "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'"

if the error is clear, I do not understand how to fix that.
I would like to get _allResults (contextName) into the list _context.
Many thanks for your help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:gtd_official_sharped_focused/models/context.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/multi_select_flutter.dart';

String taskImportant;
String taskUrgent;

class EngagePage_Sept_2021 extends StatefulWidget {
  EngagePage_Sept_2021({Key key, }):super(key:key);//this.title}) : super(key: key);
  // final String title;

  @override
  _EngagePage_Sept_2021State createState() => _EngagePage_Sept_2021State();
}

class _EngagePage_Sept_2021State extends State<EngagePage_Sept_2021> {

  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  Future resultsLoaded;
  List _allResults = [];
  List _resultsList = [];

  @override
  void initState()  {
    super.initState();
    _selectedContext = _allResults;//_context;
    _searchController.addListener(_onSearchChanged);
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _searchController.removeListener(_onSearchChanged);
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    resultsLoaded = getUsersListOfTasksStreamSnapshots();
  }

  _onSearchChanged() {
    searchResultsList();
  }

  /*static List<Contexts> _monTest = [
    Contexts(contextName:  ),
  ];
*/
  static List<Contexts> _context = [. //Here, I would prefer to store the data.docs
    Contexts(id: '1', contextName: "name 1"),
    Contexts(id: '2', contextName: "name 2"),
    Contexts(id: '3', contextName: "name 3"),
  ];

 // static List<Contexts> _test = _allResults;

  final _itemsContext = _context
      .map((context) => MultiSelectItem<Contexts>(context, context.contextName))
      .toList();

  List<Contexts> _selectedContext = [];

  final _multiSelectKeyContext = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  final _multiSelectKeyStatus = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  final _multiSelectKey4 = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  final _multiSelectKeyTime = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

  searchResultsList() {
    var showResults = [];

    if(_searchController.text != "") {
      for(var taskSnapshot in _allResults){
        var title = Contexts.fromSnapshot(taskSnapshot).contextName.toLowerCase();

        if(title.contains(_searchController.text.toLowerCase())) {
          showResults.add(taskSnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      showResults = List.from(_allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      _resultsList = showResults;
    });
  }

  getUsersListOfTasksStreamSnapshots() async {
    var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('contexts')
        .get();
    setState(() {
      _allResults = data.docs;
      print(_allResults);
    });
    searchResultsList();
    return 'complete';
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TEST CHIP'),
      ),
      drawer: MyMenu(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              //################################################################################################
              // CONTEXT - MultiSelectBottomSheetField with validators
              //################################################################################################
              MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Contexts>(
                key: _multiSelectKeyContext,
                initialChildSize: 0.7,
                maxChildSize: 0.95,
                title: Text("Context"),
                buttonText: Text("Context",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                items: _itemsContext,
                searchable: true,
                validator: (values) {
                  if (values == null || values.isEmpty) {
                    return "";
                  }
                  List<String> names = values.map((e) => e.contextName).toList();
                  return null;
                },
                onConfirm: (values) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedContext = values;
                  });
                  _multiSelectKeyContext.currentState.validate();
                },
                chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                  onTap: (item) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedContext.remove(item);
                    });
                    _multiSelectKeyContext.currentState.validate();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40),

              //################################################################################################
              // STATUS - MultiSelectBottomSheetField with validators
              //################################################################################################

              
            

                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Model context

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Contexts {
  String id;
  String contextName;

  Contexts({
    this.id,
    this.contextName,
  });

  // formatting for upload to Firebase when creating the trip
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        'context_Name': contextName,
      };

//creating a Task object from a firebase snapshot
  Contexts.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) :
        id = snapshot.id,
        contextName = snapshot['context_Name'];

}
```